# access Android phone data from computer scripting env

Tags: android, python, perl

I am planning to to manage my phone (Running Android) data (contacts, call logs, messages, reminders etc..) from my computer (it is running linux). Is there a way to access these data from within a scripting env like perl/python? I tried searching in web but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: what phone do you have?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this easily. Look what I foung on google:

- contacts : here is a guide on exporting yo
- call logs : this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dukemdev) exports it as csv
- sms : [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en) for exporting those..

This way you can save all the files you need on your computer andd access them at will..

if you mean accessing internal android API from python/Perl for developing a python/perl based app - I dont know of any such bridge. But for VB you have [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/) which works pretty well, check it out.

Good luck

Just found this - https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/ maybe this is what you need.

Comment: Yeah, i am looking for a API so that i can directly read the binary data from android db. Your suggestion is also good, i can write a app and dump all the required info to some file and read that file in perl. Thanks